# Turn A List to a Float That Can Be Divided

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, converters, currency

I've been trying super hard to make a currency converter for the world. One of the many problems I've been facing is that my currency converter wouldn't figure out the exchange rate itself; YOU had to. But of course, I figured it out.

But my question is: I got the exchange rate for EURO, but it's a list, and I need it a float to do the calculation. How would I do that?

Here is what I've tried:

```
euro_exchange = float(str(tree.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/text()')))
######################################################################
euro_exchange = tree.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/text()')

float(str(euro_exchange)
################################################################
euro_exchange = float(tree.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/text()')
```

You get the pattern. When I tried `euro_exchange = float(str(tree.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/text()')))`, it says (I'm using TkInter, BTW):

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1562, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/jboyadvance/Documents/Code/Python/Currency Converter/Alpha2/main.py", line 21, in usd_callback
    euro_exchange = float(str(tree.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/text()')))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "['1.1394']"
```

and when I tried `euro_exchange = tree.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/text()')
float(str(euro_exchange)` I got the same results.

When I tried `euro_exchange = float(tree.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/text()')`:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1562, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/jboyadvance/Documents/Code/Python/Currency Converter/Alpha2/main.py", line 21, in usd_callback
    euro_exchange = float(tree.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/text()'))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

And here's the source code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from lxml import html
import requests

window = tk.Tk()

window.title("Currency Converter")

window.geometry("500x500")

window.configure(bg="#900C3F")

# window.wm_iconbitmap("penny.ico")

page = requests.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/EURUSD:CUR')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)


def usd_callback():
    usd_amount = float(ent_usd.get())
    euro_exchange = float(str(tree.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/text()')))

    euro_amount = usd_amount / euro_exchange

    lbl_euros.config(text="Euro Amount: %.2f€" % euro_amount)


lbl_usd = tk.Label(window, text="Enter the USD ($) here:", bg="#900C3F", font="#FFFFFF")
ent_usd = tk.Entry(window)

btn_usd = tk.Button(window, text="Convert", command=usd_callback, bg="#FFFFFF", font="#FFFFFF")

lbl_euros = tk.Label(window)

lbl_usd.pack()
ent_usd.pack()

btn_usd.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Any help would be gladly appreciated! Thank you!!

Comment: What value do you get from `euro_exchange = tree.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/text()')`?

Comment: Not reading the whole code, but guessing by the error, you could do `float(yourlist[0])`

Comment: `Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1562, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/jboyadvance/Documents/Code/Python/Currency Converter/Alpha2/main.py", line 21, in usd_callback
    euro_exchange = float(str(tree.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/text()')))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "['1.1394']"` @The_Cthulhu_Kid

Comment: Type `euro_exchange` and see what it returns.

Comment: I mean without trying to convert it to float. Do you get a list of string representations of floats? Are they all valid?

Comment: Then you should do basic indexing: `float(euro_exchange[0])` to get the `1.1393` value.

Comment: I get `['1.1393']` @ViníciusAguiar @The_Cthulhu_Kid

Comment: I need to figure out how to get the number from the list. If anyone knows how to do THAT that'll be helpful!

Comment: Have you tried what @ViníciusAguiar suggested?

Comment: Yes. And I got the result from the previous traceback in the comments

Comment: Sorry, missed that! It should work though. If `euro_exchange` is a list with only one entry. Try printing `euro_exchange[0]`

Comment: I did. I got `['1.1393']`

Comment: And printing `euro_exchange`?

Comment: I did. I got `['1.1393']`

Comment: That can't be. If you are printing the list, ok. If you are printing the list one `0` index you should not be getting that result. It should be `1.1393`

Comment: Try printing `type(euro_exchange)` and `type(euro_exchange[0])`

Comment: Nope. I got `['1.1393']`

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid you mean '1.1393'

Comment: @Apaws yeah, I did. Thanks =)

Comment: @JBoyAdvance that would mean that your variable is a list of lists , and you may need to flatten it first , what do you get when you do euro_exchange[0][0]

Comment: @Apaws that is what I was meaning, just trying to get him to realise it himself =)

Comment: I got `1`. Is this bad?

Comment: Nope, it means that you have a list with a string value.

Comment: it rounded off 1.1393 to 1

Comment: And when you print `type(euro_exchange)`?

Comment: OK so how do I make this "string" into a number (float)?

Comment: @Apaws no it didn't. Print does not round. He is printing the `0` index of the string.

Comment: and I get nothing when I do `type(euro_exchange)`

Comment: `print(type(euro_exchange))`

Comment: `<class 'list'>`

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid then shouldnt [0] returned the string itself and not the list value ?

Comment: @Apaws exactly!

Comment: And when you `print(type(euro_exchange[0]))`?

Comment: `<class 'lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult'>`

Comment: Cool. Now `print(str(euro_exchange[0]))`

Comment: I got: `1.1387`

Comment: See my answer =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the first element from the return value from `xpath` :

```
euro_exchange = tree.xpath('//div[@class="price"]/text()')
euro_exchange = float(str(euro_exchange[0]))
```

Comment: I got this error: `Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1562, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/jboyadvance/Documents/Code/Python/Currency Converter/Alpha2/main.py", line 24, in usd_callback
    print(str(euro_exchange[0]))
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @JBoyAdvance What exactly did you enter?

Comment: @JBoyAdvance did you remember to remove the print statements?

Comment: It works! Thank you Apaws, The_Cthulhu_Kid and ViníciusAguiar for all your support!